# Deep Learning - maximum GPUs a CPU can handle

Tags: gpu

The design for the deep learning server would be very similar to that of a mining rig, specifically using risers to stack as many GPU's onto the motherboard. The design is as follows:

```
CPU: AMD EPYC Rome 7302P
-128 Lanes PCIe 4.0

Mobo: AsRock Rack ROMED8-2T
-Supports 7 x PCIe 4.0 x16

GPUs can be any model
```

FIRST: Is it safe to say we can run 7 GPU's (max on mobo) and utilize ALL of them at max capacity? Are there any bottlenecks concerning the hardware?

7 gpus * x16 pcie speeds = 112 lanes

My question stems from a purely hardware design standpoint, and if there are any limitations to this design. I'm trying to maximize the GPU's without resorting to building more servers, using 10GB networking equipment. I know there are dual-socket server boards that can do 4 GPUs each, but not what I'm after.

SECOND: If I run the GPU's at a slower speed, say pcie x8, can we double the amount of GPU's theoretically, provided a motherboard had enough pcie x8 slots (x8 to x16 converter used)?

Comment: Im planning to built a GOU Server with 7x 1080 ti using the Asrock Mainboard mentioned above. @invulnarable27 Do you have further insights on the quastions you mentioned above? Especially: - Can you use 7 GPUs at full load? - My research showed that the AsRock Rack ROMED8-2T supports PciE-Bifurcation, so is it possible to use 14 GPUs with 8x lanes each? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Ralf When I emailed AsRock support, their response: "Yes, but PCIe #2 is being shared with other the Mini SAS HD port or OCulink port. So if you do not use these storage ports, theoretically all seven PCIe 4.0 slots should be able to run the video cards installed. It is also highly recommended you connect another 6-pin 12v video card power to the side of the board when you have more than one video card installed." Also make sure the CPU you choose has enough lanes. I don't have any information on bifurcation, so can't say.